# Fragment$InstantiationException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have looked through questions for the same error, but I am implementing all the solutions given in the answers, but I am getting the following error in my logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.overview.LoginActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.test.base.BaseActivity$ProgressDialogFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.mint.test.base.BaseActivity$ProgressDialogFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:96)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1726)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:198)
    at com.mint.test.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:88)
    at com.mint.test.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:84)
    at com.test.base.FlipperActivity.onCreate(FlipperActivity.java:56)
    at com.test.overview.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:99)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:384)
    ... 21 more
```

In my code I have the following:

```
@SuppressLint({ "ValidFragment", "UseSparseArrays" })
public abstract class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

//The class is static and public
public static class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public ProgressDialogFragment() {} //Empty Constructor

 }
}
```

Can someone please help me identify what the problem is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this error messages

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
>       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:384)

Do you have a function named newInstance()? If so, pls post the code. 
Check this example on how to work with DialogFragments. [DialogFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Answer (score -1):

Possible you have private or protected default constructor of your ProgressDialogFragment class. Make it public or better remove constructor at all, and use onCreate() to initialize lical variables.